# How to use left join after where clause

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

```
// comment 
+----+---------+---------+----------------------+
| id | id_post | user_id |       content        |
+----+---------+---------+----------------------+
| 1  |  1111   |  2222   |   this is content1   |
| 2  |  3333   |  2222   |   this is content2   |
| 3  |  3333   |  4444   |   this is content3   |
+----+---------+---------+----------------------+

// user
+------+-----------+
|  id  |   name    |
+------+-----------+
| 2222 |   jack    |
| 4444 |   peter   |
+------+-----------+
```

And here is my query:

```
select c.content, u.name
  from comment c inner join user u on c.id_user = u.id
  where c.id_post = 3333;
```

And here is my result:

```
+----------------------+-----------+
|        content       |   name    |
+----------------------+-----------+
|   this is content2   |   jack    |
|   this is content3   |   peter   |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

---

So, **My question**: I need to add one more column contained `1` number *but just for specific user*. In other word **I want this output**:

```
// for this user: 2222 (or jack)
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
|        content       |   name    | user_id  |
+----------------------+-----------+----------|
|   this is content2   |   jack    |    1     |
|   this is content3   |   peter   |          |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+

// for this user: 444  (or peter)
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
|        content       |   name    | user_id  |
+----------------------+-----------+----------|
|   this is content2   |   jack    |          |
|   this is content3   |   peter   |     1    |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
```

I think I should use one more `left join`, but I don't know how should I add one `left join` to my query. there is any suggestion ?

Comment: Have a look at the [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `flag` in the `select`:

```
select c.content, u.name,
       (u.id = 222) as hasUserId
from comment c inner join
    user u
    on c.id_user = u.id
where c.id_post = 3333;
```

I should note:  the above returns 1 or 0.  If you want 1 or `NULL`:

```
select c.content, u.name,
       (case when u.id = 222 then 1 end) as hasUserId
```

Comment: OMG ! +1 vote up for you !! very thanks. just two thing, your approach is faster or using of one more `left join` ? and may please explain me this line `(u.id = 222)` ? [the name of this line is `flag` ? and when you set it `1` number ?]

Comment: A `case` statement is going to be faster than another `join`, unless you have really, really complicated logic in the `case`.  MySQL treats a boolean expression as a number with 1 for true and 0 for false, so `u.id = 222` is basically shorthand for `case when u.id = 222 then 1 else 0 end`.

Comment: aha I see, I don't know how say you thanks :-). I learned some new stuff :-)

Comment: Is it possible to set a value after `then` ? `case when u.id = 222 then u.content = 1 else u.content =2` is it possible ?

Comment: @Sajad . . . The syntax is `(case when u.id = 222 then 1 else 2 end) as content`.